# std::string::iterator to offset and back

Tags: c++, iterator, stdstring

- Can I set an iterator to position 5 in a string via some member or do I have to do a `for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) iterator++;`?
- Given an Iterator, how can I convert that to a numeric offset in the string?
- If this is not possible with std::iterators can boost do it?

Iterators <-> Offsets

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Can I set an iterator to position 5 in a string via some member

You can use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

```
std::advance(iterator, 5);
```

or

```
iterator += 5;
```

> Given an Iterator, how can I convert that to a numeric offset in the
>   string?

You can use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

```
std::distance(string.begin(), iterator);
```

or

```
iterator - string.begin()
```

Answer (score 7):

std::string iterators are random access iterators, which define the +operator. You can get a iterator to position 5 with `begin(str) + 5`. Offset can be computed via `std::distance` which uses -operator for random access iterators.

Answer (score 3):

1. you can use 
   `iterator + 4`
2. try this: `iterator - str.begin();`
3. iterator has operator `+` and `-` ; you can use these to convert between iterators and offsets.